# Regex in C#: match string thats preceded and/or followed by "_" or " " or ""

Tags: c#, regex, string, pattern-matching

lets assume i have a word like "aus" and i want to replace all occurences of it with "off". Then i also want to find all possible spellings of it like "AUs", "aUs", "AUS" and so forth. But its important that its only replaced when it "stands alone" as in has only a space, an underscore (_) or nothing in front and/or after it
so it should be replaced in

```
" aus"
"aus"
"_aus"
"_aus_"
"aus_"
```

But not in

```
"ausschalten"
"aushebeln"
" ausschalten"
```

I tried `^(_| )(A|a)(U|u)(S|s)(_|)$` but its not working right :/

Comment: [\s_]?([AUSaus]+)[\s_] works with the words you have provided

Comment: @SørenLorentzen: However, it won't work with " aus," and it will also match `suauuua`.

Comment: `^(_|\s)?(A|a)(U|u)(S|s)(_|\s)?$` you was amost right just needed to add ? so it can exist or not

Comment: the replace results should look like this then: " off" "off" "_off" "off " "off_" for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of lookarounds and a `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag (or its inline version `(?i)`):

```
@"(?i)(?<![\w-[_]])aus(?![\w-[_]])"
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fi)(%3f%3c!%5b%5cw-%5b_%5d%5d)aus(%3f!%5b%5cw-%5b_%5d%5d)&i=aus%0d%0a%22+aus%22%0d%0a%22aus%22%0d%0a%22_aus%22%0d%0a%22_aus_%22%0d%0a%22aus_%22%0d%0abut+not+in+%0d%0a%22ausschalten%22%0d%0a%22aushebeln%22%0d%0a%22+ausschalten%22)

*Explanation*:

- `(?<![\w-[_]])`  - check if before `aus` there is no digit or letter character (using *character class subtraction*, I removed `_` from `\w` class)
- `aus` - literal character sequence `aus`
- `(?![\w-[_]])` - check if after `aus` there is no letter or digit.

A [simpler alternative](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fi)(%3f%3c!%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cp%7bN%7d%5d)aus(%3f!%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cp%7bN%7d%5d)&i=aus%0d%0a%22+aus%22%0d%0a%22aus%22%0d%0a%22_aus%22%0d%0a%22_aus_%22%0d%0a%22aus_%22%0d%0abut+not+in+%0d%0a%22ausschalten%22%0d%0a%22aushebeln%22%0d%0a%22+ausschalten%22) with `\p{L}` (any Unicode base letter) and `\p{N}` (any digit):

```
(?i)(?<![\p{L}\p{N}])aus(?![\p{L}\p{N}])
```

Comment: Just a note on `(A|a)(U|u)(S|s)` syntax: redundant alternation should be avoided as often as possible - in this case, you could use `[Aa][Uu][Ss]` if there was no case insensitive flag in .NET regex (as is the case with the HTML5 pattern attribute regex).